# Amplitude on competitors' websites

Tags: analytics, amplitude-analytics

I am going to start learning Amplitude Analytics, could you tell me if Amplitude can be used on the websites of my competitors, to know how their customers behave with them.?

Still to try and find out.

Answer (score 1):

Well even if that was possible, that would be pretty unethical.

But it's not possible. Amplitude, as well as any other tracking script, has to be deployed to a page in order for it to start being tracked.

You surely can deploy it locally on your version of the page, but then you'd only be able to track yourself.

For competitor assessment, you typically use your broad market assessment tools that give you approximate numbers based on analysis of things like behavior of people using certain extensions, or estimations based on search engine result page rankings by search frequency of particular keywords, or self-declared revenue numbers. There are many legal ways to get an estimation.